# I need to make a dvd converted to a mp4 for my TV

Tags: dvd, convert, mp4

I bought a DVD for my son but our DVD player is not reading it ; I think it is broken somehow. While my notebook can read DVD I want to make this animation DVD convert it mp4 or something else that can be played on TV so I can copy to my USB and play I don't want to share my notebook with my son :D

thanks

Comment: please note that you can copy the entire DVD into a USB DOK, and use VLC to open the DVD folder in the USB as DVD

Comment: dear @Yaron I allready use dd command to make its iso and figure out that I can not play it on my TV :D

Comment: I didn't refer to `dd`, If you open the  DVD you'll see that it holds several directories with files, you can try to copy those directories into a USB stick, and use VLC ->Open DVD to play the content from the USB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure to follow [this instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs) in order to enable support for commercial encrypted DVDs before using any conversion tool.

When done you can use the great [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) for ripping/converting to MP4  MKV. Handbrake is free, reliable and very user-friendly, for the most part intuitive, but slower than many paid software for Windows. he official website link is FYI only. The software is now available directly at the Ubuntu repositories.It can be installed with Ubuntu Software or, in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install handbrake handbrake-cli
```

Comment: thanks I will try and I saw that many people suggesting it ; I hope I can use that;btw  sorry my repu is not enough to give upvote :( people love giving downvote to my questions and I became looser :D